# поиск данных в Big data, Python

Tags: python, join, big-data, apache-spark, pyspark

У меня есть большой фрейм на 100+ миллионов строк (пусть будет f1) и второй на 5 миллионов (пусть будет f2). [image: пример фрейма на 100 миллионов]

[image: пример фрейма на 5 миллионов]

Мне нужно сравнить все строчки по сразу по 3 столбцам, типо 1f.client == 2f.client_pin AND 1f.session_id == 2f.session_id AND 1f.timestamp == 2f.timestamp, и все строчки в которых все совпало вынести в еще один отдельный фрейм. Задачу выполняю в Google Colab, по этому нужны не сильно тяжёлые для железа решения. Очень бы хотелось решение через Pyspark.

Comment: Пожалуйста, замените  в вопросе картинки текстом.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = f1.join(f2.withColumnRenamed("client_pin", "client"), 
              ["client", "session_id", "timestamp")
```

Comment: как отобразить результат? даже через show(1) не подгружает.

Comment: @TROSHER, что значит "не подгружает"? Вы дождались пока отработает `join` ?

Comment: да, но полученный результат не грузиться. даже если пытаюсь одну строчку отобразить.

Comment: @TROSHER, `res = f1.join(f2...)` -  отработает мгновенно из-за `lazy execution`, фактическая обработка данных начинается только тогда, когда вы пытаетесь обратиться к результату - т.е. `res.show(1)` - сначала сделает `.join()`, а потом покажет вам первую строку результата. Join с вашими таблицами будет выполняться долго. Если хотите проверить функциональность решения - создайте два тестовых датасета с 5-10 строк и посмотрите как все работает...

Comment: Все проверил, работает. спасибо)

Comment: @TROSHER, [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow) ;)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Сколько времени заняло это сравнение с выводом результатов?